# How do a replace an old baseboard thermostat with a wifi thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I don't know if this is a dual pole or single pole thermostat (n00b here, don't know what I'm talking about). I don't even know what voltage this is (240 or 120).

But here's a photo of the wiring: 
[image]

I bought a [wifi Honeywell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y6M2OUC) which includes a number of different wire connections in the back (says, "will not operate without the wire C connected"): 
[image]

1) **Will this work, or do I need a different thermostat for a baseboard heater?**

2) I see three wires connected to the old, knob-driven thermostat: red, black, and white. BTW, the old thermostat says Load is black and Line is red. **Which wires do I connect to which terminals on the new wifi thermostat?**

FYI, I did turn off the power at the breaker. That switch connects to 3 thermostats+baseboard heaters in total. The thermostat I'm working on is only connected to one heater.

Answer (score 1):

### Get a different 'stat

The thermostat you have is designed for low voltage (24VAC) systems such as gas furnaces and heat pumps.  You'll need a line voltage thermostat instead (and yes, wifi line voltage 'stats are a thing.)